# How can you store and display upvotes and downvotes made by users in an efficient way as seen on reddit?

Tags: javascript, mysql, user-interface, feed

When you upvote or downvote on reddit you can see your upvotes and downvotes at all times.

[image]

No matter if you clear your cookies or not it is always there so it is not being saved in cookies. How are they able to keep track of this and show it to the user in such an efficient way?

It doesn't seem like a good idea to fetch all of the users likes on posts and comments and cross check them with the feed on every page load?

I did not know where else to ask. Please consider the question.

Comment: try to log out and see if it still knows your votes :)

Comment: They are still there even if I log out. So they must be saving it somewhere in the backend.

Comment: did you check the localStorage?

Comment: I cleared the localStorage but the upvotes are still shown.